# Triple SELECT from the same table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to group all these queries within the same table:

```
SELECT orgname, COUNT(username)
FROM `user`
GROUP BY orgname;

SELECT COUNT(username) AS 'users_with_2FA'
FROM `user`
WHERE two_fa_enabled = 1
GROUP BY orgname;

SELECT COUNT(username) AS 'users_pending_2FA'
FROM `user`
WHERE two_fa_required_date IS NOT NULL AND two_fa_enabled IS NULL
GROUP BY orgname;
```

Comment: Hint: use `case` expressions to do _conditional aggregation_.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this using CASE as suggested by @jarlh

```
SELECT orgname, COUNT(username) AS 'users_all'
    , SUM((CASE WHEN two_fa_enabled = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'users_with_2FA'
    , SUM((CASE WHEN (two_fa_required_date IS NOT NULL AND two_fa_enabled IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'users_pending_2FA'
FROM `user`
GROUP BY orgname;
```

Comment: #1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: Edited with SUM().  Please try now